# wrap_content, fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an alertDialog to ask for a login data.

I would like to use all the horizontal space, but I can't get it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder loginData = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    loginData.setTitle("Tus datos");
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(activity);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    LinearLayout linea1 = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linea1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linea1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final TextView Usuario = new TextView(activity);
    Usuario.setText("Usuario");
    linea1.addView(Usuario);

    final EditText usuario = new EditText(activity);
    linea1.addView(usuario);

    layout.addView(linea1);
    // Set an EditText view to get user input

    LinearLayout linea2 = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linea2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    linea2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final TextView Contrasena = new TextView(activity);
            Contrasena.setText("Contraseña");
            linea2.addView(Contrasena);

    final EditText contrasena = new EditText(activity);
            linea2.addView(contrasena);

    layout.addView(linea2);

    loginData.setView(layout);

    loginData.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    try{
                      //do the work 
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

    loginData.show();   
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
     ..... 
     usuario.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     .....
     contrasena.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
     .....
```

But in my opinion - you should use xml for layout.

dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Usuario"
                />
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contraseña"
                />
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In activity:

```
   ....
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder loginData = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    loginData.setTitle("Tus datos");
    loginData.setView(layout);
    loginData.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            try{
                //do the work
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    loginData.show();

   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post you the correct code, but I think you must use fill_parent for width and height. I always use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

in my layout xml files.

Comment: fill_parent will not actually do as you wish in an AlertDialog. Please see my answer for how you would go about adjusting the width and height of a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the width of the Display, and then adjust the LayoutParams of the AlertDialog based on the display width. I would advise you add 10% padding to the width so that the whole screen is not filled.

Another choice is to apply a Theme to your activity which resembles a Dialog, this will allow you to use the whole width.